# How to copy all content of a scrollview?

Tags: android, scrollview, copy-paste

I would like to copy the content of my scrollview by pressing on it (long clickable).

My scrollview contains a textview (I took the code from FloatingActionButtonBasic sample) :

```
<ViewAnimator
    android:id="@+id/log"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="4dp"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

    </ScrollView>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.logger.LogFragment"
        android:id="@+id/log_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</ViewAnimator>
```

How can I copy my entire log (I don't want to save appending a string each time I write in scrollview, because this functionnality would not be used often, only for debug purpose) ?

Thanks !

Comment: have you tried using clipboard in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Provide an `id` tag to your Text View

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="4dp"
    android:typeface="monospace" />

TextView txtV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtId);
txtV.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
           String txt = v.getText()
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Save the string txt where ever you want.

Comment: How dit OP put something in there without id?

Comment: I tried to add listener to the ViewAnimator, the ScrollView, and TextView, but nothing happens when I long click on it...

Comment: Can you post your code , because ideally it should work.

Comment: It's exactly the same code as in the Google samples (with LogFragment, LogWrapper, LogView, LogNode...). I took it in the Floating Button sample.